# Spring Boot App - Reference external code during runtime that isn't part of the bundled WAR?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jakarta-ee, jar, osgi

I have a Spring Boot+React application that is packaged as a bundled WAR.

This works well for most cases, but we need to be able to drop-in functionality in some cases that is not part of the bundle (such as via a JAR).

I knew OSGI exists for this case, but not sure of any usage with Spring Boot. Is there another way to do this as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your use case is a kind of small plugin functionality for your spring boot app then you could start an OSGi framework inside spring boot and load bundles from a separate directory. You plugins could then offer their service via an interface that is provided by the spring boot app and an OSGi service with that interface.

You need some good OSGi knowledge for this to work.